# Get elapsed time just seconds in c++

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I need to get the elapsed time from a while.

```
something.start()
auto start = std::chrono::steadyt_clock::now();
while(something->is_valid())
{
    // getting frames
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto diff = end - start;
    // do something with the frames
    if(diff % 3 == 0) { /* do something with the something */ }

}
```

But it get the time in every ms i get the time and my if statement runs too much. I can not use std::this_thread::sleep_for() cause i need every frame to catch. How can i do it pararell?

Comment: Are you asking how to do [duration_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast)?

Answer (score 4):

Since C++14 you could do `diff >= 3s` to see if the difference was equal or bigger than three seconds (see [this duration literal reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Literals)).

Otherwise if you're stuck with C++11 then use `diff >= std::chrono::seconds(3)`.

Note that this requires you to reset `start` each time the condition is true:

```
if (diff >= 3s)
{
    start = end;
    // Do something with the something...
}
```

This is required because the difference could stay equal to `3` (and therefore `diff % 3s == 0` being true) for up to a whole second, which means your "Do something..." part will execute many times falsely.

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, but that's kind of required anyway, since almost no duration is going to be an ***exact*** multiple of three, leading to `diff % 3s` being wrong sometimes.